# SoundCloud API: /connect 'state' parameter not working

Tags: soundcloud

Trying to integrate SoundCloud Auth into my android application. Currently, I have my server creating a SoundCloud client and then retrieving a authorize URL. This is simply explained in the SoundCloud API; however, I want to add a user_id to it so that when the user pings the redirect URL (which is a link on my server) I then have their user_id and access_token to save as a key-value pair to my database.

The way I would like to achieve this is by adding the user's user_id to the redirect url before they are given the authorize URL. Because when the redirect_url hits my server, I will know which user it came from.

I am trying to store it is the 'state' param. On Soundcloud's api it says I can store any string there and it will be appended on the redirect url, but so far it hasn't worked.

If anyone could help that would be amazing, thank you.

Image to help describe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2ymu.jpg